# Facebook page app

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-page

I`m an admin on a facebook fan page. The problem is that when I try to create an app for facebook fan page, facebook redirects me to my profile, and thus I will be creating an app for myself and not the facebook fan page.

Is there a way to do this?

I need to do this so I would get app ID and app Secret for facebook fan page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kalvin Klien, please don't fall over getting out of bed, but you will need to use a user profile to create apps, not a page profile.  It is documented here:

[Create new app from Business account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8434865/create-new-app-from-business-account)

[Create a Facebook APP goes in circles back my page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8625284/create-a-facebook-app-goes-in-circles-back-my-page)

[Can company page accounts create apps?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8536378/can-company-page-accounts-create-apps)

If you want facebook to tell you, please

1) Log into your facebook account

2) Switch to using your facebook page (aka business page)

3) Go to: **https://developers.facebook.com/apps**

4) Read error message that says:

> To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your
>   page to using Facebook as yourself.